# How to reach resources inside a method within RecyclerView's class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a "insert_data()" function in same class with RecyleView's adapter class. With this method, I'll populate an array.

That method works after clicking an "setOnClickListener".

So onBindViewHolder method's codes are below,

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: adsViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.txt_ads.text = category[position]


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(){


            if (holder.itemView.txt_ads.text.contains("Estate")){

                var arrayID = holder.itemView.resources.getIdentifier("EstateCategory","array", holder.itemView.context.packageName )
                var category_arraylist = ArrayList<String>(9)

                i**nsert_data(category_arraylist,arrayID)**

                var mylinearlayout = LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.layoutManager = mylinearlayout

                var myadapter = adsRecyleAdapter(category_arraylist)
                holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.adapter = myadapter
            }
        }
    }
```

and "insert_data()" method's codes are below,

```
fun insert_data(categoryArraylist: ArrayList<String>,arrayID:Int) {

    var obje = AppCompatActivity()

    var Category = obje.resources.getStringArray(R.array.EstateCategory)

    for (i in 0..obje.resources.getStringArray(R.array.realEstateCategory).size -1 ){

        categoryArraylist.add(Category[i])
    }
}
```

Wtihin this method, I cant reach "resources". To solve this, I created and object from AppCombatActivity class. But it gives error like below at "var obje = AppCompatActivity()" line.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

How can I reach resources with this method? "this", or "context" doesn't works.

Comment: You can add resources as constructor parameter to your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the `itemView` into the `insertData` method and call the resources the same way you're calling them in other places

```
insertData(itemView: View) {// along with your other parameters

    itemView.resources.getStringArray(..)
}
```

Comment: Rafa, I guess I should call this method like this? I mean itemview parameter should be like this? " insert_data(category_arraylist,arrayID, holder.itemView)"